# Horizontally align 3 divs

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have 3 divs that I want to align horizontally, I have used this code for other divs on my site and they are working, is there something I am missing in these ones? [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KarinaMcG/6Lrdp/4/)

```
#christmas_product_boxes{width:1000px; height:auto;}
.christmas_boxes {float:left; width:300px; height:auto;}
.christmas_boxes + .christmas_boxes {margin-left:20px;}
.christmas_boxes > div {width:300px; height:auto; clear:both;}
.christmas_mattress_title {color:#000000;}
.christmas_pillows_title {color:#2B436B;}
.christmas_beds_title {color:#333333;}
.christmas_mattress_text {font-size:13px;}
.christmas_pillows_text {font-size:12px;}
.christmas_beds_text {font-size:11px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the sub boxes needs to have the `.christmas_boxes` class, like this:

```
<div id="christmas_product_boxes">
    <div class="christmas_boxes">
        <div class="christmas_mattress">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="christmas_boxes">
        <div class="christmas_pillows">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="christmas_boxes">
        <div class="christmas_beds">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```